# Wrap domain roles around aggregate root operations to represent the ubiquitous language

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, user-roles, event-sourcing

In a BC I have the following rules:

```
A project can be defined by an employer.
An approver should approve the project.
Then an employee can bid that project.
A project can be directed by a member (= an employer or an employee) to another member.
```

The project is an independent aggregate from employer, employee, and approver.

And employer, employee, and approver are all users and all I need to know from users in this BC is their Identities.

I designed the project including methods :

```
static Define(){...}
ApprovedBy(approderId){...}
Bid(bidderId){...}
Direct(directorId,directeeId){...}
```

How should I apply the rest of ubiquitous language to the context?

Should I skip `Users` in this context or create classes for employee, employer, and approver and make for example the the `Approve` method internal so that limit the app layer only be able to approve a project through an `Approver` class like the following?

```
class Approver{
    approverId _id 
    public Approver(approverId id){
        _id = id
    }
    public Approve(project){
       project.ApprovedBy(_id);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here are some comments Iv'e written on answers that may make the question clearer:

`Approver` is a role that defined in `Identity and Access BC`, and the only thing should match is it's role name.`Bidder` should had filled out some additional data than a regular member to be able to `bid a project`. I wanted to use a `saga` and listen to `events` to check if the bidder is satisfied the rule, then the `saga` sends `AddRole()` or `RemoveRole()` to I&A BC. I thought this way I have a more cohesive `I&A` concern which is separated from the rest of the system but when I was designing the `Project BC` I thought why do not call something like `factories.Employer(‌​employerId).DefinePro‌​ject(..)`

**BUT**

I'm worrying about is **future** features that would grow after the initial release.They may expect more rules for the `Employer` for example,and as I started add them to the BC,I'll have to break my tests to avoid the `Project` from leaking the responsibilities of the `Employer`,for example I should no more be able to call `DefineProject()` as a `static factory` (or `constructor`),and the only way of defining a `project` should be calling `Employer.DefineProj‌​ect();`and I feel the natural place that the `Approvement` should be concerned is the `Approver` class.Do you think I'm over engineering?

One of reasons that we encapsulate everything even identities in another object in ddd is taking care of the change of requirements independently by defining explicit contracts between objects and letting them change their internal implementations in another context.The PO doesn't care much about identities but he explicitly talks about roles and their rules.That can affect my tests and service layer codes later. Shouldn't I take care of roles at least as much as identities? Or I misunderstood something about boundaries and contracts?

Can explicit abstract `role contracts` act as a potential `anti corruption layer` `interface` which can keep me away from breaking the `OCP`?

Comment: Would Approver, Director and Bidder classes have any other logic?

Comment: @tomliversidge:Not yet in this BC.

Comment: I wouldn't bother then, just stick to the first code example

Comment: Regarding the BUT : I think you're doing *premature* engineering. Model the domain as it is now. It will always be time to make changes when new requirements come.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't model the operations on the actors because the natural home for operations are aggregates. However, you could get role security checks for free and have a strong alignment with your Ubiquitous Language if you model the roles explicitely. The explicit roles would become part of the anti-curruption layer and the classes could be instantiated by a service that abstracts away the integration with your Idendity & Access BC.

E.g.

```
Approver approver = actorService.approverOfId(userId);
project.markAsApprovedBy(approver);
```

This approach is discussed in Vaughn Vernon's IDDD book and [blog post](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=250).

Comment: How about `approver.Approve(project)` as I mentioned in the question? since the project knows nothing about the approver but it's `Identity`. `project.approve(approver);` seems not add anything special but the overhead of querying another BC and coupling the `project` with an approver anemic model,and in the blog post you linked, this part is omitted;

Comment: I do not think that you can speak of anemia with value objects (that is what `Approver` would be. It's actually quite common to have behaviorless values given that value objects are immutable, especially if you use value objects as a mean to enhance the language and enforce constraints through contracts. Your BC has to be coupled to the Identity & Access BC, how will you check security rules otherwise? Even if you do so in the application services without involving the domain it's still coupling. The anti-curruption layer limits that coupling though and that's a good thing.

Comment: I guess that you could always use the same approach, but model the operation on the `Approver` instead but then following this road you will end up with a ton of methods on actor classes that basically just dispatch to aggregates.

Comment: You are right,but I'm worrying about is future features that would grow after the initial release.They may expect more rules for the `Employer` as example,and as I started add them to the BC,I'll have to break my tests to avoid the `Project` from leaking the responsibilities of the `Employer`,for example I should no more be able to call `DefineProject()` as a static factory,and the only way of defining a project should be calling `Employer.DefineProject()`;and I feel the natural place that the `Approvement` should be concerned is the `Approver` class.Do you think I'm over engineering?

Comment: You mean that an `Employer` may not have to right to create a project in certain scenarios? For instance, he shouldn't be able to create more than 3 active projects? Well I do not think that this rule belongs to `Employer` either. I'd encapsulate this kind of rule in a policy object instead. The rule would much likely be eventually consistent.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what to think of modeling operations on roles. I've never done it or seen it in action. I'd ask your question on [this forum as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs).

Comment: Thanks so much;I did, this is the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/XjyLLqIj78o

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is business logic that would be better represented by having separate classes, I wouldn't bother creating Approver, Director and Bidder classes. It sounds like this context doesn't need to know anything other than the ids associated with them. So just keep it simple with the model you currently have.

This advice would probably change if you had a situation, say where an Approver or a Director had other details that determined their permission to do certain actions. For example, take StackOverflow - maybe a User needs a certain amount of reputation to be an Approver, or maybe Directing between two members needed other business rules applying to make to a valid transfer. These sort of scenarios might be better modelled as classes.

Comment: `Approver` is a role that defined in Identity and Access BC, and the only thing should match is it's role name.Bidder should had filled out some additional data than a regular member to be able to bid a project. I wanted to use a saga and listen to events to check if the bidder is satisfied the rule, then the `saga` sends  `AddRole()` or `RemoveRole()` to I&A BC. I thought this way I have a more cohesive I&A concern which is separated from the rest of the system but when I was designing the `Project BC` I thought why do not call something like `factories.Employer(employerId).DefineProject(..)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you have defined your contexts but I'll try to give a reasonable answer regardless.

> 1. All your requirements have the `<ROLE>` being able to do something.
> 2. That tells me that you need a `<ROLE>` aggregate for your code to match the language in your requirements (for you to create a proper ubiquitous language)
> 3. My answers assume an aggregate for the roles.
> 4. You can ofcourse redesign a little and make things cleaner by using inheritance or other patterns that augment your code but I am not tackling any of those here

Let's take your requirements one at a time:

## A project can be defined by an employer

It sounds like a project can `ONLY` be defined by an employer. In which case, you do need to be able to tell whether your current user is an employer or not.
There are a few questions here but one of hte bigger ones is:

**Where do you validate to make sure the user is an employer?**
Your factory method.
So:

`ProjectFactory.Create(User: Employer)`

I generally prefer to use a factory method that's part of an aggregate.

Something like:

`Employer.createProject(someProject: Project)` This lends itself well to the Ubiquitous language because an employer is Creating a project.

```
class Employer{
    Project[] projects{get; private set;}
    //you can also pass primitives as parameters so the consumer doesn't
    //need to bother with knowing how to create a project.
    //furthermore, you could use a factory to get just the project
    Project createProject(someProject: Project)
}
```

## An approver should approve the project

`Approver.approve(someProject: Project)` This also lends itself well to the ubiquitous language. The interesting thing is how will you save this state? In the previous example about creating projects, it's easy to come to the conclusion that Employer will have a collection of projects and createProject will add to that collection. In this case, What will your method actually be doing? I think it makes sense to have your method modifying state in the specific project. Approver will serve as an aggregate and Projects are value members.

## Then an employee can bid that project.

This could be done as a bid service or as a method in the User Aggregates like the ones above. Which one makes sense depends on your specific requirements and your specific usecase. If the bid is supposed to be persisted to a datastore as soon as it's made then you want to consider a service. If the bid can be persisted at the same time as the aggregate, then a method in your aggregate is fine.

## A project can be directed by a member (= an employer or an employee) to another member.

This sounds like a service to me.

`TransferService(proj: Project, User1: User, User2: User)` This fits better because in a lot of cases there are complex rules governing things like transfer that the user aggregates don't know or care about.

Comment: Please take a look at comments I added under @tomliversidge's answer.That seems get you more information about my domain.

Comment: I read it. Regardless, you can apply any or all I have said to your specific usecase. ;)

Comment: Why should I keep `approver.ApprovedProjects` in memory? An approver can approve more entities from several contexts and I was trying to keep it away from making other BCs dirty.I want to have a preferably NoSql read model of aggregates should become approved, and when the approver approves them, by sending a request to the underlying BC.

Comment: It's whatever fits your usecase/requirements the best. My assumption was that Approvers can only approve projects that they own or have being assigned to. One reason you would keep approvals in memory is if you wanted to commit all at once or implement a sort of transaction for your system. Functionalities such as `undo` are better done in memory as well. Ultimately though, it depends on the problem/task you have in front of you

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

Remember that your model is only a representation that is useful for your context (set of requirements). If your requirements change it's only natural that your model will evolve. So, a test breaking is a good thing. I understand that you want to anticipate change but do not overthink it too much. Maybe the business will just be happy with Role Based Access control.

How about instead of using "Approver" in your "IAM BC" you introduce the "Project Member" or "Team Member" concept in your "Project BC". The member is a role that a Party (employer, employee, and approver) plays within the project context:

```
ApprovedBy(memberId){...}
Bid(memberId){...}
Direct(directorId,directeeId){...}
```

Like this your project only needs to know about members. Or the other way around. your parties only need to know about the roles they play. So Project and your parties are decoupled. Also, one Employee can play multiple roles on projects (as a team member).

You might need to integrate (anti-corruption layer?) between "Identity and Access BC" and "Project BC" in case your roles change which might impact your project/project members.

Comment: So you say being explicit about members and their roles can be implicit in this `BC` and let another `BC` handles them.That can work perfect in situations that you are sure about your next requirements would grown.And one of reasons that we encapsulate everything even `identities` in another object in `ddd` is taking care of the change of requirements independently by defining explicit contracts between objects and letting them change their internal implementations in another context. The PO doesn't care much about identities but he explicitly talks about roles.

Comment: That can affect my tests and service layer codes later. Shouldn't I take care of roles at least as much as identities? Or I misunderstood something about boundaries and abstractions?

Comment: Yup, make the UL clear by making the implicit explicit. A UL term has meaning within a specific (bounded) context: For example "Role" in "Project BC" vs "Role" in "IAM BC" are different things. If your PO just uses the term "Role" it’s ambiguous so you need to refine the UL and get agreement on a preferred term like "Project Member". Synonyms concept like "Project Role" or "Team Member" can be noted in your UL (glossary/thesaurus) as non-preferred terms which point to "Project Member" (preferred term) or even better just "Member". 
Maybe you’ll agree on another term with your business.

Comment: I would thus put Member and MemberId (identity) in the Project BC and use UserId (identity) for correlation with the IAM BC. 

Refactor of your domain model based on your **current** requirements set due to deeper domain knowledge. You domain model will stabilize over time since your business domain does not change… in Eric’s Blue Book he uses the concept of a garden glove must be in the section "Part III: Refactoring Toward Deeper Insight"